# How to use JavaScript in Selenium C#.net?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I export the test case as a cs file from Selenium. I want to get all objects under the window during run time, so I selected JavaScript for that.

How to use it in cs file?

Please give some example or list the ways to get the objects from window in Selenium cs test case.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `selenium.GetEval()` for JavaScript, and get Object from form using

```
selenium.GetEval("window.document.getElementsByTag('form').elements");
```